# How to break if statement

Tags: javascript

I have two for loops and I am checking one if condition in inner for loop.
I want to stop inner for loop once if condition is true.
How can I do that?
Below is my code.

```js
for (let index = 0; index < devices.length; index++) {
    var myObject = {};
    const Id = devices[index].UUID;
    for (let index1 = 0; index1 < list.length; index1++) {
      if (list[index1] != null && list[index1].name !== null) {
        const bleId = list[index1].id;
        if (Id === bleId) {
          // console.log("match");
          myObject['Id'] = devices[index].UUID;
          myObject['Name'] = devices[index].Name;
          finalList.push(myObject);
          break;
          // console.log("myObject ---------> ", finalList)
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: You would typically do this by setting a flag and then breaking from the inner loop if the flag is set. Alternately, wrap this routine in a function and `return` out of it when your break condition is hit.

Comment: You break loops, not `if` statements, which run only once..

Comment: Can you show code?

Comment: As @ChrisHelad suggested, define `var flag = false` outside the first for loop and then if your condition is met than make this flag variable true by `flag = true` in _inner for loop_ and add another if condition in the body of _outer for loop_ that `if (flag==true){break;}` .

Comment: What are you trying to achieve and what doesn't work? From the question, I understand that you want to break the inner loop when the `if` is  entered, which should work because of the `break`. If it doesn't, the problem is likely something else. If you want to break the outer loop, use labels, as mentioned in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @FZs pointed out, `break` statements take affect on the loop they are in (not the outer one) by default. if you need to break the outer loop, you can use [labels for for loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)

```
loop1: for (let index = 0; index < devices.length; index++) {
    var myObject = {};
    const Id = devices[index].UUID;
    loop2: for (let index1 = 0; index1 < list.length; index1++) {
      if (list[index1] != null && list[index1].name !== null) {
        const bleId = list[index1].id;
        if (Id === bleId) {
          // console.log("match");
          myObject['Id'] = devices[index].UUID;
          myObject['Name'] = devices[index].Name;
          finalList.push(myObject);
          break loop1;
          // console.log("myObject ---------> ", finalList)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

If you don't want to run the inner for loop ever again for the ongoing *outer* `for loop`, you have to define a variable(flag).

```
let idFound = false
for (let index = 0; index < devices.length; index++) {
    var myObject = {};
    const Id = devices[index].UUID;
    if(idFound){
      for (let index1 = 0; index1 < list.length; index1++) {
        if (list[index1] != null && list[index1].name !== null) {
          const bleId = list[index1].id;
          if (Id === bleId) {
            myObject['Id'] = devices[index].UUID;
            myObject['Name'] = devices[index].Name;
            finalList.push(myObject);
            idFound = true
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code works. From your comments, I understand that you don't want to run the inner for loop ever again, for continuing iterations, once the condition is checked. Is that correct?

Comment: How would this change anything on the OP's code? Targetting the inner loop with labels won't help (`break` targets the innermost loop/`switch` by default); if, on the other hand the OP wants to stop the loop after the `if` executed for the first time, you could just `break` the outer loop **with a label**. However, the question is unclear, so we should await the OP clarify it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, corrected the misinformation.